# Image Slider with recyclerview scrolling

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, androidimageslider

I have a bit of a problem with the **SliderView** I created. The **sliderview** can not be scrolled at the same time as the **recyclerview**. I've tried adding ScrollView but it still seems to be still.

Here is the layout:

fragment_home.xml

```
<FrameLayout 
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        <LinearLayout
        <RelativeLayout
            <RelativeLayout
                <FrameLayout
                    <com.mimdudin.carekkerje.Activities.SliderView
                </FrameLayout>
            <View />
            <LinearLayout
        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please be more specific and give more detail. Does your SliderView works vertically or horizontally? What is your main problem? What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: My SliderView works horizontally, underneath there is a recyclerview. when i scrolled, this sliderview is not hide. I want to when to scrolling, the imageslider will hide @OğuzhanDöngül

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, your achievement is hiding, scrolling or collapsing your **SliderView** which is placed above your **RecyclerView**.

You have different options here. Choose one of them and make some research, you can find lots of documentations and tutorials about them.

1. Add your `SliderView` as an item of `RecyclerView` and add it to first position. (like a HeaderView used in ListView)
2. Use **CollapsingToolbarLayout** and put your SliderView as a collapsable view when the RecyclerView scrolls to bottom and expands when you scroll to top.
3. You can use `CoordinatorLayout` **behaviors** to hide and show your slider with animations according to RecyclerView scrolling statuses.
4. Use **NestedScrollView** and put your SliderView and RecyclerView inside.(setting **nestedScrollingEnabled** true/false is the trick)